# React native throws an error inside try {}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, try-catch

I installed [RNUI](https://wix.github.io/react-native-ui-lib/) to a fresh Expo project. After simply importing the module it throws this error:

```
Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/
 • should NOT have additional property 'nodeModulesPath'.
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve module react-native-haptic-feedback from /Users/xx/Documents/yy/zz/node_modules/react-native-ui-lib/src/optionalDependencies/HapticFeedbackPackage.js: react-native-haptic-feedback could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  2 |
  3 | try {
> 4 |   HapticFeedbackPackage = require('react-native-haptic-feedback').default;
    |                                    ^
  5 | } catch (error) {}
  6 |
  7 | export default HapticFeedbackPackage;
```

It seems very illogical to me that it throws an error inside a try {} statement. The same module worked fine in an older Expo project (older version).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `react-native-haptic-feedback` this package, and then to it doesn't work perform the steps given below.

Delete the **node_modules** folder in the project directory, close the metro bundler and everything that is running for the project. Now run npm install it should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for proposing an answer. The problem here is that the module contains a lot of optional dependencies, and throws the same error for every of them. I tried deleting node_modules, changing versions, etc. but none of these work

Comment: Hi, you followed the installation process correctly?

Comment: Hi Mihir, yes I have installed it following the docs.